# Block dynamic Nginx location

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am trying to block request to Nginx for dynamic location.

```
location ~ (21277765e65e4441|55cf7r34bf364e95) {
    return 444;
}
```

This is working fine but I don't wanna edit the location each time I block a new location containing the unique ID. Instead can I have a file in the location directive and add in the unique ID's to the file and nginx picks up the change without reload?

Comment: You can not. But you can use `try_files $uri $uri/ =444;` so that any location that does not exist will be served with status code 444.